# Declaratively created Content type does not contain site columns

Tags: 2013, content-type, site-column, versioning

In Visual Studio I have created a Content Type and site columns declaratively. I have added `FieldRef` to the content type for each site column. When I deploy the solution, the content type contains the site columns, however when I add a new site column to the project (declaratively) and redeploy the solution the content type does not contain the new site columns. why and how do solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the previous content type before deploying the latest one. In some cases the removal will fail because its being using in the Site.

The best practice in such situation is to use another feature with a receiver, the receiver is the one which make the updates (in your case adding a new site column)

More details on this topic

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592295/best-practices-for-content-types-in-sharepoint